# Глобальный хук на мышь срабатывает несколько раз в "многооконных" приложениях

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook

Создаю приложение на Delphi - счётчик щелчков мыши. Написал глобальный хук на мышь. Сделал все, как рекомендовано, поместил его в DLL. Отслеживаю, отпускание кнопки (`WM_LBUTTONUP`). В "простых" приложениях (Рабочий стол, Notepad, Total Commander) работает без претензий. А вот в сложных многооконных приложениях, например - в любом браузере, в Delphi IDE, срабатывает два раза (считает, как два щелчка). В Microsoft Word, так вообще - то четыре, то девять, то пять.

Пробовал сделать задержку (а ля, дребезг контактов - debounce). Пробовал очищать очередь в обработчике нажатий (счётчик в главной программе - мониторе). Без результатов.
Подскажите пожалуйста, идеи или направление мысли куда двигаться.

Код глобального хука в DLL:

```
// Ловушка отпускания левой кнопки мыши
function GMouse_Hook(Code: Integer; wParam: Word; lParam: LongInt): LongInt; export; stdcall;
var
  H: HWND;
  x, y: Integer;
  HookData: tagMOUSEHOOKSTRUCT;
  xy_param: LongInt;
begin
  if Code >= 0 then
    begin
      HookData := PMouseHookStruct(lParam)^;
      x := HookData.pt.X;
      y := HookData.pt.Y;
      xy_param := x shl 16 or y;   // передаем координаты как значение, а не как адрес на структуру

      if wParam = WM_LBUTTONUP then
        begin
          H := FindWindow('TfrmGMouseHook', nil);
          SendMessage(H, WM_GMOUSEHOOK_UP, 0, xy_param);
        end;

      Result := 0;
    end
  else
    Result := CallNextHookEx(HookHandle,Code, wParam, lParam);
end;
```

Comment: Самый простой способ (и не самый правильный) запоминать время последнего нажатия. Если меньше 0,1 сек - игнорируем. Но по нормальному нужно было бы разобраться откуда двойные нажатия.

Comment: Тоже думаю об этом. Сделаю статус и буду менять его в таймере.  По "простоте душевной" ))) с чего-то решил, что если в программе-мониторе-счетчике, в обработчике сообщений  сделать задержку, то пока программа "спит" лишние сообщения улетят в воздух. Само собой нет. Поэтому чистил очередь (PeekMessage(Msg, 0, WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST, PM_REMOVE); , но эффекта это не дало.
Думаю это связано именно с MDI-приложениями. Для проверки свою MDI-программу накидаю, может тогда что прояснится. Спасибо.

Comment: @VladChapl Сделал через статус в таймере, как мы с вами предполагали. Всё сейчас работает, как надо. Но это можно сказать - "Костыль". Просто хотелось бы услышать, от знатоков  архитектуры Windows с чем это может  быть связано ?